# Распознать текущее место местоположение c googleapis и предоставить погоду в этой области используя openweathermap в jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, api

Пытаюсь распознать текущее место местоположение и предоставить погоду в этом городе(районе).

Вот мой код **jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){


    function getPosition() {
       if (navigator.geolocation) {
           navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(getCity);
       } else {
           alert("Geolocation is not supported by this browser.");
       }
       }

          function getCity(position) {
             var url =  "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json? latlng=" + position.coords.latitude + "," + position.coords.longitude;

             var city,
             country;
             $.getJSON(url, function(response) {
                city =  response.results[0].address_components[2].short_name;
             country = response.results[0].address_components[5].short_name;
             $('.yourLocationGoesHere').attr('value', city + ", " + country);
             });

             // Get weather by your location
             $.getJSON("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=" + city + "&APPID=7f5806c8f3fd28b03e2d6580a50732d6", function (data) {

             var celsius = Math.round(data.main.temp - 273.15);
             var fahrenheit = Math.round(9/5 * (data.main.temp - 273) + 32);
             var iconCode = data.weather[0].icon;
             var iconUrl = "http://openweathermap.org/img/w/" + iconCode + ".png";
             $(".icon").html("<img src='" + iconUrl + "'>");
              });

              $(':radio').change(function(){ 
              // "this" will be the checked radio element       
              if (this.id === 'celsius'){
                 $(".showDegree").html(celsius + "&degC");
              }else{ 
                  $(".showDegree").html(fahrenheit + "&degF");
                }
               });
              }
```

Что я делаю не так. Подскажите пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1):

Первое - Вам нужен https, чтоб получить доступ к geolocation html5

Второе - получайте данные на сервере, к примеру

```
$getWeather = @file_get_contents('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat='.$lat.'&lon='.$lng.'&appid='.$appid);
```

client

```
function getWeather(position) {

             // Get weather by your location
             $.getJSON("/getWeather?lat=" + position.coords.latitude + "&lon="+position.coords.longitude + "&appid=7f5806c8f3fd28b03e2d6580a50732d6", function (data) {

             var celsius = Math.round(data.main.temp - 273.15);
             var fahrenheit = Math.round(9/5 * (data.main.temp - 273) + 32);
             var iconCode = data.weather[0].icon;
             var iconUrl = "http://openweathermap.org/img/w/" + iconCode + ".png";
             $(".icon").html("<img src='" + iconUrl + "'>");
              });

              $(':radio').change(function(){ 
              // "this" will be the checked radio element       
              if (this.id === 'celsius'){
                 $(".showDegree").html(celsius + "&degC");
              }else{ 
                  $(".showDegree").html(fahrenheit + "&degF");
                }
               });
              }

navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
  getWeather(position);
});
```

Comment: Александр, спасибо за ответ, это мой второй проект с курса freecodecamp и я совсем запутался, не могли бы вы более развернутый ответ дать, я так же обновил codepen https://codepen.io/ekilja01/pen/rjMQEG

Comment: Ваш сайт( или страница) должен иметь SSL сертификат, чтобы запросить доступ к geolocation html5 api. С этим понятно ?

Comment: Честно, нет. Если есть возможность, объяснить я буду очень признателен, а если нет то сам буду делать research.

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTPS . С установкой возможно поможет ваш хостинг-провайдер

Comment: А дальше? Для чего мне это?

Comment: Я же написал, чтобы получить доступ к geolocation.